# The layout display wrongly on the simulator

Tags: android

I write this code on fragment and everything is fine when i edit it on XML(You can see it on my first image) And when i run my simulator ,the layout display like this (You can see on my second image ) I think the problem is the whole layout goes down so we can only see  a few part of my layout

HELP ME OUT

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="198dp"
            android:layout_height="182dp"
            android:src="@drawable/liuruiquan"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XoBD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIb07.png)

Comment: Euhm I think you've uploaded the same picture twice, there is no difference between them.

Comment: I have already edited it

Comment: I think you might have missed "app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"" while running in simulator.It works fine for me

Comment: May be there is a problem in your layout which you use to show the fragment? Set the different background color to your ConstraintLayout in this fragment and look does it take all place.

Comment: Please don't create the same question again just to draw attention to it. We asked you on the other threads to provide us with the layout where the fragment is used. As it is shown here there's nothing wrong with this layout.

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. Edit your original question to include all the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="182dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_flat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```